# Keeping Active Directory free of stale objects

Tags: active-directory, exchange, windows-server-essentials

We mainly run a 2003 orientated environment. Soon we will be moving towards a clean slate of 2008 EBS. My main concern is the AD/network legacy that has accumulated over the years will be difficult to remove.

Running the Windows Essential Business Server Preparation tool it gives me errors about stale Exchange objects in AD. What would be the best/safest way to remove these stale objects and any other out dated objects that would cause problems to implementing Essential Business Services 2008?

Or more broadly, what are some effective methods for keeping AD clean and tidy? (I guess with respects of upgrading to 2008 from 2003)

I know about the **dsquery** command for AD, if this could be used to remove stale exchange objects that would be helpful too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual the Event log will be the first place to stop for answers.
Then I'd run the Exchange Best Practices Analyzer to try to pinpoint the faults.
Without know exactly which objects are reported as stale, determining what to remove is hard. Could you post the exact error messages from EBS prep tool?

Comment: (I'm scanning it with the Exchange Analyzer atm), EBS Prep tool gives: Error: A list of Exchange Servers could not be collected from Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS). Ensure that stale Exchange Server objects do not exist in AD DS.

Comment: Did you have any luck with ExBPA?

Comment: Yes, it turns out we still have an old sub domain that is full of stale objects including stale Exchange servers. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Ah, there you go.. :)